# How to pass a SAFEARRAY from C++ to C# via COM

Tags: c#, c++, com

I'm writing C++ code that uses an COM-interface to an ECAD-System. I'm trying to achieve to get a list of materials that are used by the ECAD-System.

The problem is, that the documentation of the API is for C#:

[image: Fuction to extract material list from ECAD-System when using c#]

When I call this function in C++, the declaration is the following:

```cpp
void Physics_GetMaterialList(SAFEARRAY * * saMaterials)
{
    static BYTE parms[] = VTS_UNKNOWN;
    InvokeHelper(0xf, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, nullptr, parms, saMaterials);
}
```

This declaration raises some questions to me:

- I´m not really into SAFEARRAYs, but as far as my attempts have shown, I always need to declare a length of the SAFEARRAY (which later is the number of used materials) which I don't know at the moment when I call this function.
- I don't know the type which to use for the SAFEARRAY (maybe VT_BSTR?)

My attempt so far:

```cpp
try
{
    DWORD dwDims[] = {100};

    COleSafeArray values;
    values.Create(VT_BSTR, 1, dwDims);

    SAFEARRAY* materialList = values.parray;

    Physics_GetMaterialList(&materialList);
}
catch (CMemoryException* e)
{
}
catch (CFileException* e)
{
}
catch (CException* e)
{
}
```

Which leads to an Access violation during execution.

Any suggestion of how to pass a SAFEARRAY to C# that is in C# a System.Array?

Comment: That function creates the array for you.  When you pass an existing array then it has to destroy that one, then create the new array.  Problem is that the one you pass has not been initialized correctly, the array elements were not assigned.  Next logical thing to try is SAFEARRAY* materialList = NULL;

Comment: Thx for your answer. Set SAFEARRAY* materialList = NULL.

result:  Access violation during execution

Comment: Consider using `CreateOneDim()` instead of `Create()`, and set the number of elements to 0. But don't use a separate `SAFEARRAY*` pointer variable at all. You are letting the function modify that pointer instead of the pointer inside the `COleSafeArray`. If the function reallocates the array memory, the `COleSafeArray` is left dangling. Try this instead: `COleSafeArray values; values.CreateOneDim(VT_BSTR, 0); Physics_GetMaterialList(&(values.parray));`

Comment: On a side note, you need to catch thrown exception class types by (const) reference, not by pointer

Comment: Are you sure the C/C++ header is the one you show here? If there's a TLB (or the COM dll contains one), you can check what the standard OleView tool shows when it rebuilds an hypothetical IDL. Plus there are chances that it will also add in/out/etc. annotations to make sure who's supposed to allocate/free what. Otherwise you can try `SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 0)`;

Comment: @RemyLebeau thx for your tips! Your suggest leads to "Debug Assertion Failed", so still not working :/

Comment: @SimonMourier I have to admit I'm not sure, because I'm not really into using COM. I'll try to figure out if I can find another header. Using `SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 0)` also leads to Access violation during excecution